# CakePhp: auto redirect to login page

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have used Auth component of Cakephp to redirect to login page after session out but I want it to redirect automatically using ajax.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't understand your question... Already redirect to login page after session out. Then redirect automatically using Ajax???

Please clarify your questin

Comment: I want to redirect to login page automatically after some idle time. Now what it does is,  after session out, it stays in the same page and after some activity then it redirects to login page

Comment: I would say to write a script that store the session time.. and check/compare the time with the time limit. You can constantly check it.. But its not nice to run js for every second. So i would suggest you use delay function and only check when it reach your time limit.